# Put jQuery code inside css expression

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a kind of drop down menu with highlighted active menu items: http://jsfiddle.net/4r5vg/105/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="navlist">
    <li id="home"><a class="nav" href="home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li id="about"><a class="nav" href="about-us">About Us</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#navlist a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#navlist a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

**CSS**

```
    .selected {
        font-weight:bold;
}
```

Is that posible to put jQuery code inside `.selected` using expression to make a link bold?

Comment: No, you can't put JavaScript inside a CSS file

Comment: You want to make all links bold or you want to assign css value through jQuery?

Comment: you want the link to be bold when it's active?

Comment: @tymeJV read about css expressions

Comment: @coderman -- CSS expressions are so old and deprecated tho.. In place of that are media queries and using JavaScript to achieve what you need.

Comment: @jmore009, yes, I already have it, but I need to know if is it possible to put this code inside css expression

Comment: Dynamic properties (also called "CSS expressions") are no longer supported in Internet Explorer 8 and later, in IE8 Standards mode and higher. This decision was made for standards compliance, browser performance, and security reasons, as detailed in the IE blog entry titled Ending Expressions. Dynamic properties are still available in Internet Explorer 8 in either IE7 mode or IE5 mode.  CSS expressions are no longer supported in any modern browsers

Comment: @coderman -- As I said in the first comment - it's not possible. Explain a little more the desired outcome and I'm positive there's a workaround

Comment: whats wrong with a simple `$(".selected").css({"font-weight":"bold"});` ? why complicate things?

Comment: @coderman - The point is that *css expressions* are long deprecated, and you'll be able to achieve what you want by other ways... So make clear what you really want to happen...

Comment: @tymeJV Thanks for your answer, that's all I need to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately, css is a styling markup and not a programming language. you cannot use jQuery or javascript inside a css block. you may want however, to look into [**LESS or SASS**](http://css-tricks.com/sass-vs-less/).

instead of trying to complicate things, you can just write in simple jquery on page load, (or rather DOM ready)

```
// this block runs once dom is ready
$(function(){  
    //thats your bolding code
    $(".selected").css({"font-weight":"bold"});
});
```

it achieves the same results, without complicating things.